# Can't query special characters (ü,ß etc.) by sqlalchemy

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

**SOLVED**

I have to set the enviroment variable NLS_LANG (oracle) likes this:

```
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = nls_lang
```

in my example, nls_lang is GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8 to fetch all german umlauts and special characters.

---

I want to query some table data from an oracle database. I use the following part to connect to the database:

```
            self.engine = create_engine('{}://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(type,
                                                                     user,
                                                                     password,
                                                                     server,
                                                                     port,
                                                                     dbname),
                                        echo=log,
                                        pool_size=4000,
                                        max_overflow=400)
```

To select the needed columns i'm using a black- or whitelist function:

```
tmp_all = None
        # get session
        session = self.Session()
        # Blacklist
        if bwtyp == "B":
            tmp_all = session.query(*[c for c in tableo.c if not bwlist.is_column(schema, tabname, c.name)])
        # Whitelist
        if bwtyp == "W":
            tmp_all = session.query(*[c for c in tableo.c if bwlist.is_column(schema, tabname, c.name)])
        # close session
        session.close()
        return tmp_all
```

Now i iterate trough my resultset like this:

```
for row in tabledata.yield_per(buffersize).enable_eagerloads(False):
```

The resultset is almost okay, but here is the difference:

- Every ü is displayed as u.
- Every ß ist displayed as ?.

*Screenshot from debugger*
[image: Figure 1]

*Screenshot from database*
[image: Figure 2]

[screenshot of charset from database][3]

I did a lot, put charset to connectionstring etc. but nothing worked.
Maybe u can help. Thanks a lot in advance.
JR